# Cordova4.1.1の脆弱性について

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

AndroidのPlayストアでCordova4.1.1の脆弱性について警告が出ていますが、
これは放置するとストアから自動的に削除されてしまうものなのでしょうか？
もし削除されてしまった場合、脆弱性を修正したもので更新することで、
復活させることができるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 4):

段階として下記のようになります。

１．脆弱性への告知
２．脆弱性への警告と修正期限の告知　←いまここ
３．脆弱性を含んだアップデートが出来なくなる。
４．ストアから削除される（アプリが非公開になる）

……とはいえ、修正期限後、直ぐに削除されることはありません。
また、脆弱性へ対応したアップデートを行うことで再度公開できます。

直近の脆弱性のお知らせだと7/10にOpenSSLの脆弱性への対処だったかな？
どの脆弱性だったかストアの対応番号を記載いただかないと分からないですが、
Cordova自身のバージョン(フレームワーク)のみだけでなく、
使っているプラグインの中のOpenSSLバージョンも審査されるのでお気をつけください。
対処・確認方法はストアでの警告(黄色い三角形)からのヘルプに書いてありますので今一度確認してみるといいかもです。